# AS2 Flash Input Text Problem

Tags: flash, utf-8, input, actionscript-2

Well I've big problem and no idea how to sort it out. I've made a form in Flash using input text fields. The point is i'm Polish so our customers expect so they can put a polish character inside the input text field ( ex. źćż etc ). The problem occurs on WebKit Engine Browsers ( Safari, Chrome ) which just put normal characters ( l instead of ł ) like i wouldn't hold my ALT key. Internet Explorer and Firefox don't have such problems ( while Opera prevents from typing anything in ).

So far I've tried few things, also customizing input charactes, trying different fonts, using the System.useCodepage directive etc. Anyone has at least idea, a mark from which I could follow ? Is it my mistake or it's rather Adobe's bug.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would recommend not setting [System.useCodepage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001578.html), in almost all cases it is better to leave it at its default (false), and thereby go with Unicode for all text.

If you embed and use a custom (not web standard) font, then you need to select all the Unicode character sets that is need for the application, like "Latin Extended A" (I believe) for Polish.

The font used also need to have all the characters, like ł, which is not the case with all custom fonts.

If you don't need to embed a custom font, and choose a web safe font, like Verdana, then you can select "device font" for anti-aliasing, and the user will be able to type whatever characters their installed font supports.

Yet another alternative, kind of like a last resort, is to select the "_sans", "_serif" or "_typwriter" fonts, that are mapped to fonts similar to Arial, Times and Courier respectively, on the users device.

Comment: Thank you. Using device fonts worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch again.